# Wordpress : How set and expiration date for RSS Feeds

Tags: rss, wordpress, feed

First of all, thanks for your attention,

Second, the problem.

Well, I need to make RSS items disappear after a determined date, let us say, 15 days.
I would like to know if there is an "easy" or "right" way to do so.

Also, if there is any plugin that already has this configuration or something like this, just name it and I'll happily search for it.

Once again, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A simple filter on `posts_where` for feeds should work fine:

```
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_feed_by_days');

function filter_feed_by_days($where) {
    global $wpdb;
    if (is_feed()) {
        // Take 15 days backwards from now, and convert to GMT to compare
        // with post_date_gmt in the database.
        $time_limit = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-15 days'));
        $where .= $wpdb->prepare(
            " AND $wpdb->posts.post_date_gmt >= %s ", 
            $time_limit
        );
    }
    return $where;
}
```